# Vue-js-modal resizable issue

Tags: css, vue.js, modal-dialog

By default, vue-js-modal scales from the central point, which is pretty strange. Is it possible to scale it like all other windows (according to one of the edges)?

EDIT
On the official page (http://vue-js-modal.yev.io/), when you 'click' resizable, you can see what I mean. In the docs there is a line, which describes 'resizable' attribute: "If true allows resizing the modal window, keeping it in the center of the screen". I didn't find other info and don't want to change the source code. I don't want it to be keeping in the center, because I think that this is not correct.

Comment: Could you provide some code, please? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've edited my question. Sorry for the lack of info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS styles to configure it manually before Overlay

```
.v--modal-overlay{
//add style like u r requirement
}
```

In style, you can also  add these line to make it left align after it overlays

```
v--modal-box v--modal.{
left:0px !important
}
```